# org hyperlink multiple actions

Tags: org-mode, shell

How do you execute multiple actions on a single org-link?

Org-mode has [links that can initiate actions](http://orgmode.org/org.html#External-links), such as `elisp:` and
  `shell:`. It would be nice to initiate several such actions on
  following a single link.

Just creating a shell-file containing the tasks is possible, but
  seems inelegant.

How is this best done?

Comment: Is chaining multiple actions in an elisp form (via `progn`) and using `elisp:(progn ...)` a possibility?

Comment: @Kevin: sounds good. How would you execute multiple shell commands that way? The method at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecuteExternalCommand?

Comment: This may be relevant: http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/02/22/org-mode-links-meet-hydra/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate shell commands with a `;`, like so:

```
[[shell:whoami%3B%20id][Two commands]]
```

The link you type in would be `shell:whoami; id` (it's stored in the document with special characters encoded).

Similarly, for Emacs Lisp, the link you type in might be:

```
elisp:(progn (message "Hello") (message "World!"))
```

Comment: For shell scripts, `cmd1 && cmd2` might be better as it only executes the second command if the first succeeded.

Comment: Works for several shell commands or several elisp commands. How would you execute two shell commands and then open a file?